# How to benchmark a single algorithm in SUPERCOP?

Tags: algorithm, benchmarking

A full SUPERCOP benchmark is done as follows:

```
wget https://bench.cr.yp.to/supercop/supercop-20170228.tar.xz

unxz < supercop-20170228.tar.xz | tar -xf -

cd supercop-20170228

nohup sh do &
```

But it takes too much time to run every cryptographic algorithm benchmark.

I wondered, if you know how to benchmark only Ed25519 in SUPERCOP, without benchmarking all the other algorithms. 
Ed25519 is in the crypto_sign/ed25519 folder of SUPERCOP.

Answer (score 1):

The SUPERCOP tips page (https://bench.cr.yp.to/tips.html) suggest something like this:

```
 ./do-part used
 ./do-part crypto_sign ed25519
```

Comment: Do you know where to find the actual results of the benchmark? (ie. cycles/byte, throughput, etc) The `data` file it generates isn't really human-readable. I suppose it actually contains all the information I need, but it needs to be analyzed/converted by some tool to become readable...

Comment: Sorry I haven't really used supercop, so don't know.